# setValue() or setFormula() with complex formulas/"You do not have permission to call setFormula"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-custom-function

So I keep getting this error message in my spreadsheet when I try to run my code in google script:

> You do not have permission to call setFormula.

I tried with both setValue() and setFormula() and the error is the same. I saw somewhere that setFormula() only works with simple formulas (ex. A2*B2/C2).

This is a simple function to concat a hyperlink to the content of the selected cell and forma a hyperlink sintax.

```
function HIPERLINK() {
      var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var cell = ws.getActiveCell();
      var auto = cell.getValue();
      var link = '=HIPERLINK("https://projudi.tjpr.jus.br/projudi/processo/buscaProcesso.do?actionType=pesquisaSimples&-H&Host:&projudi.tjpr.jus.br&-H&User-Agent:&Mozilla/5.0&(Windows&NT&6.3;&WOW64;&rv:49.0)&Gecko/20100101&Firefox/49.0&-H&Accept:&text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8&-H&Accept-Language:&pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3&--compressed&-H&Referer:&https://projudi.tjpr.jus.br/projudi/processo/buscaProcesso.do?actionType=iniciarSimples&-H&Cookie:&projudiContCookie=0;&JSESSIONID=053165f8dd5f8532c326f3eb06d7;&projudi-route=4;&dtLatC=54;&dtPC=-;&dtCookie=49542FA50EF89B032E8685F08394F120|UHJvanVkaSstK0V4dGVybm98MQ&-H&Connection:&keep-alive&-H&Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:&1&--data&page=1&flagNumeroUnico=true&flagNumeroFisicoAntigo=false&numeroProcesso='
        +auto+'";"'+auto+'")';
      cell.setFormula(link);
 }
```

If anyone knows a way to do this without the error message, thanks.

Comment: Can I ask you about the method for running the function of `HIPERLINK()`?

Comment: IIRC, I don't think that `HIPERLINK` is the right spelling for a hyperlink.

Comment: @Edric my gs account is set up in Portuguese. If I put hyperlink it automatically changes to Hiperlink.

Comment: @Tanaike it comes back as a named hyperlink in the cell (url, [link_label]). It's the same as hyperlink(), but in portuguese.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way and it worked for me without issues:

```
function setCustomLink(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue("https://projudi.tjpr.jus.br/projudi/processo/buscaProcesso.do?actionType=pesquisaSimples&-H&Host:&projudi.tjpr.jus.br&-H&User-Agent:&Mozilla/5.0&(Windows&NT&6.3;&WOW64;&rv:49.0)&Gecko/20100101&Firefox/49.0&-H&Accept:&text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8&-H&Accept-Language:&pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3&--compressed&-H&Referer:&https://projudi.tjpr.jus.br/projudi/processo/buscaProcesso.do?actionType=iniciarSimples&-H&Cookie:&projudiContCookie=0;&JSESSIONID=053165f8dd5f8532c326f3eb06d7;&projudi-route=4;&dtLatC=54;&dtPC=-;&dtCookie=49542FA50EF89B032E8685F08394F120|UHJvanVkaSstK0V4dGVybm98MQ&-H&Connection:&keep-alive&-H&Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:&1&--data&page=1&flagNumeroUnico=true&flagNumeroFisicoAntigo=false&numeroProcesso=" + cellValue + ";" + cellValue);
}
```

Let me know if you get different result.

**Tip**: 
you can create a button and assign setCustomLink function to it, and when you need reformatting just click the button.

Here is the link how to accomplish this: [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

Comment: Yes, it did work! Thank you! I only had to change the value so it could read as a formula on the cell.